# context.load_cert_chain and 'OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssl, webserver, pyopenssl

I have an issue, which I can't solve alone

**What I try to do:**

I want to program a https (SSL) webserver for my future project.

**What I have done:**

Nothing, because of this error

**Problem description:**

To test SSL I copied the SSL webserver code from the python documentation.

I created a certification and a private key and then I ran my program and got the following error after typing in my passphrase I've set up before in the private key:

```
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.pem", keyfile="private.pem")
```

This throws an: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` after typing the passphrase for my private key

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had a password in my key file, but forgot to add the password parameter in the load.cert_chain call. The line below worked. Would have been nice if the error message was more specific instead of "OSError: [Errno 22]."

```
ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain("server.pem", "server.key", password="xxxxx")
```

Comment: But how does this help if you have no password? Having no password is also valid.